# Is there a way to check all the python modules that are currently installed that can be accessed directly from the terminal?

Tags: python, pip, module, package

Some python modules like `pip, venv, streamlit, etc` can be accessed by directly typing them and hitting enter in the terminal.

I recently started using `pip-tools` and although `pip-tools` can be seen listed in the output of `pip freeze`, the actual commands that can be accessed from the terminal directly are `pip-compile` and `pip-sync` and not `pip-tools`. Neither are `pip-compile` and `pip-sync` listed in the output of `pip freeze`.

This has me wondering how to list down all such python modules that can be accessed from the terminal directly because clearly `pip freeze` does not list everything. I did some basic digging on the internet but only found stuff that tells me do `pip freeze`.
So, how to check what are the options I have when it comes to accessing python modules directly from the terminal?

**TL;DR**,
I tried doing `pip freeze` but `pip-compile` and `pip-sync` are not listed and only `pip-tools` is but you can only use `pip-compile` and `pip-sync` as a command directly in the terminal.

This is not a question about how to use `pip-tools` but what is the way to list down all the available python modules that can be accessed from the terminal directly in a particular environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip-compile` and `pip-sync` are not python modules or pacakages themselves, but rather scripts/commands that are distributed by `pip-tools` (you can see this declared in [pip-tool's pyproject.toml file](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/blob/main/pyproject.toml#L68-L70)).

To see python packages in your current environment you can run `pip freeze` (assuming you are doing package management with `pip` and not something like poetry). In your example you will not see `pip-compile` or `pip-sync` because these are commands and not packages.

To see *commands* that are in your current PATH and are distributed by python packages I just generally use `ls` (this assumes you're on Linux or Mac OS). It's a bit more straightforward when using a virtual environment because everything is self-contained and you can run something like (substitute in the real path to your virtualenv here):

```
ls ~/venvs/my_awesome_venv/bin
```

If you're not in a virtualenv but instead have packages installed user or system-wide, try running `which python3` to grab the path to the python interpreter, and then `ls` that directory. There will be a bit more to sort through, but this will get you closer.